# Call to a SOAP Web Service throws an Exception

Tags: android-studio, soap, webservice-client, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to call a SOAP Web Service but I get an Exception with the message
"W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException"
I have tested the Web Service in SOAPUI and everything is ok.
The particular WebService doesn't send any parameters, it only takes a response with some information from server.
Here is my code...

```
package com.example.soaptest6;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    ListView lView;
    String resp="";
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lView);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }


    public void getWs(View v){
        MyTask mt = new MyTask();
        mt.execute();
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask{

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            loadData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
            parseXML();
        }
    }

    public void loadData() {
        String wsdl_url = "http:............";
        String soap_action = "urn:..........#........";
        String name_space = "urn:........";
        String method_name = ".........";

        //Initialize soap request + add parameters
        SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(name_space, method_name);


        //Declare the version of the SOAP request
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        //put all required data into a soap envelope
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

        //Needed to make the internet call
        HttpTransportSE htse = new HttpTransportSE(wsdl_url);

        try {
            //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
            htse.call(soap_action, envelope);

            // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
            SoapObject obj = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            resp = obj.getProperty(0).toString();
            System.out.println(resp);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here is the error

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
        at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:130)
        at com.example.soaptest6.MainActivity.loadData(MainActivity.java:98)
W/System.err:     at com.example.soaptest6.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:62)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/System.err: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.finish(ExpatParser.java:549)
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:316)
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:279)
W/System.err:     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:390)
W/System.err:     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:187)
        at com.example.soaptest6.MainActivity.parseXML(MainActivity.java:117)
        at com.example.soaptest6.MainActivity$MyTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:69)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

How can I solve this?